# Application Layout control and font-awesome

Tags: xpages-extlib

I am using the application layout control from the extension library. In my application banner links I would like to include icons from font-awesome but I do not manage to achieve this.

Someone to the rescue?

Answer (score 0):

Balassaitis says everything I was going say only better and with pictures: https://xcellerant.net/2014/04/07/implementing-font-awesome-4-0-3-in-xpages/

NOTE: the FA classes don't work with the *img* tag. Use the *i* tag in your source instead.

Comment: question is: how can I refer to fa classes when in the application layout control I can only assign images to a node?